# Can we send multiple messages to a single SNS topic using a single AsyncPublish sns call?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-batch

I have a use case where i need to send one or more messages to a single sns topic in one asyncPublish sns call. Is there a possible way by which i can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Publish()` command:

> Sends a message to an Amazon SNS topic or sends a text message (SMS message) directly to a phone number.

It only sends a single message.